# Matrix.postScale produces pixelated image

Tags: android, matrix, camera, gallery

I'm using a [library](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow) that extends the Gallery view.
However, I'm having a problem with the unselected items being pixelated. Digging into the code, I suspect that this is the function that does the image manipulations based on the input.

My question is that, is there a way to ensure that when the code calls postScale on the image matrix, my images wont get pixelated?

Hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

The value of `unselectedScale = 0.2f`

```
 @Override
protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation t) {
    // We can cast here because FancyCoverFlowAdapter only creates wrappers.
    FancyCoverFlowItemWrapper item = (FancyCoverFlowItemWrapper) child;

    // Since Jelly Bean childs won't get invalidated automatically, needs to be added for the smooth coverflow animation
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        item.invalidate();
    }

    final int coverFlowWidth = this.getWidth();
    final int coverFlowCenter = coverFlowWidth / 2;
    final int childWidth = item.getWidth();
    final int childHeight = item.getHeight();
    final int childCenter = item.getLeft() + childWidth / 2;

    // Use coverflow width when its defined as automatic.
    final int actionDistance = (this.actionDistance == ACTION_DISTANCE_AUTO) ? (int) ((coverFlowWidth + childWidth) / 2.0f) : this.actionDistance;

    // Calculate the abstract amount for all effects.
    final float effectsAmount = Math.min(1.0f, Math.max(-1.0f, (1.0f / actionDistance) * (childCenter - coverFlowCenter)));

    // Clear previous transformations and set transformation type (matrix + alpha).
    t.clear();
    t.setTransformationType(Transformation.TYPE_BOTH);

    // Alpha
    if (this.unselectedAlpha != 1) {
        final float alphaAmount = (this.unselectedAlpha - 1) * Math.abs(effectsAmount) + 1;
        t.setAlpha(alphaAmount);
    }

    // Saturation
    if (this.unselectedSaturation != 1) {
        // Pass over saturation to the wrapper.
        final float saturationAmount = (this.unselectedSaturation - 1) * Math.abs(effectsAmount) + 1;
        item.setSaturation(saturationAmount);
    }

    final Matrix imageMatrix = t.getMatrix();

    // Apply rotation.
    if (this.maxRotation != 0) {
        final int rotationAngle = (int) (-effectsAmount * this.maxRotation);
        this.transformationCamera.save();
        this.transformationCamera.rotateY(rotationAngle);
        this.transformationCamera.getMatrix(imageMatrix);
        this.transformationCamera.restore();
    }

    // Zoom.
    if (this.unselectedScale != 1) {
        final float zoomAmount = (this.unselectedScale - 1) * Math.abs(effectsAmount) + 1;
        // Calculate the scale anchor (y anchor can be altered)
        final float translateX = childWidth / 2.0f;
        final float translateY = childHeight * this.scaleDownGravity;
        imageMatrix.preTranslate(-translateX, -translateY);
        imageMatrix.postScale(zoomAmount, zoomAmount);
        imageMatrix.postTranslate(translateX, translateY);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `zoomAmount` used in `postScale`?

Comment: btw in this [image](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/ef5ced52b7b54652b50499521ed797c0188c7a6b/687474703a2f2f64617669647363687265696265722e6769746875622e696f2f46616e6379436f766572466c6f772f73637265656e73686f74322e706e67) the unselected items are not pixelated, so i dont really see what kind of problem you have